# Register multiple services in .net core 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have defined two services.

```
public class FirstService : IFirstService
{
}
public class SecondService : ISecondService
{
}
```

Each of the corresponding service interfaces implements main service interface IService.

```
public interface IFirstService : IService
{
}
public interface ISecondService : IService
{
}
public interface IService
{
}
```

To register and use each of the services injecting via DI I have to register each of them like this.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IFirstService, FirstService>();
    services.AddScoped<ISecondService, SecondService>();
}
```

Is there any way to register all services in another way using IService. I want to avoid typing each defined service.

Comment: If both services are set up to inject for an `IService` dependency, how would the DI determine which service to inject?

Comment: See this tweet: https://twitter.com/thereformedprog/status/1009791758207803392 - Full text: "I have produced a new library [NetCore.AutoRegisterDi](https://github.com/JonPSmith/NetCore.AutoRegisterDi) which automatically registers classes in an assembly into ASP.NET Core's dependency injection service. See [this article](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/asp-net-core-fast-and-automatic-dependency-injection-setup/) for a full rundown of what it can do."

Comment: https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Autofac library https://autofac.org/ and reflection to register all services. 
Here you have Autofac's documentation for that: https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/scanning.html